# I can no longer access localhost in Mac OS 10.6.8

Tags: macos, apache, localhost

I was trying to update PHP from 5.3.26 to 5.5 and things have gone sideways on me. Right not the problem I think that I need to address is that I cannot connect to localhost. I honestly do no know if I messed anything up through terminal or not, but if I run "sudo apachectl start" everything seems to be OK, but when I try it from a browser, the all say unable to connect. I may have other issues as well, but I don't know enough to test anything else until I can get this working.

It worked for me yesterday, and initially I was getting cached responses in the browser which further confused me. The cache is all clear though now, and I get nothing.

Does anyone have a suggestion that can be understood by an artist/designer? Thank you ...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: OK, thank you. As you can probably tell, I really don't know where to begin with this.

Comment: @jww Please ***do not encourage people to cross-post***. Good questions can be migrated. Also, when pointing people to other [SE] sites remind them to check that site's [help] for topicality. In particular [SF] is for *System Administrator (et al) only*, questions from an artist are automatically off-topic there.

Comment: @ChrisS - Hugh? The question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. teemflmngo was told where the question may be on-topic as a courtesy. As for the placement (SU vs SF), its not clear to me how you made the distinction given teemflmngo's problem statement. He may be an admin at a small organization; or he may be working from his basement.

Comment: My name isn't Hugh. Questions can be migrated from one site to another if they fit the other site more appropriately. [Posts can not be migrated from SO to SF by normal users anymore because too many migration were rejected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152596). [Cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/). The OP explains that he is an artist/designer in the Question and his profile.

Comment: @Chris - I'm beginning to think your name is something else. It does not matter whether the user can migrate his post or not - the question does not belong on SO, and it belongs on another site. It does not matter if he's an artist, executive a trash man - he's operating in the capacity of a system administrator, so the question is on topic for either SU or SF.

Comment: @Chris - "...do not encourage people to cross-post. ..." - I was not encouraging anyone to post to multiple places. I was stating the obvious - the question belongs on SU or SF. He can decide where to put it.

Comment: @teemflmngo - the spat between Chris and myself is no reflection on you. I think its an ok question, and its ok that you are an artist. Please don't take it personally. You will encounter folks on occasion who can be rude, condescending and arrogant. They will criticize you and down vote you rather than taking the time to explain things to you or offer you alternatives. See, for example, [Could we please be a bit nicer to new users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users).